# Expectation of the Max of iid Bernoulli distributions

Tags: expected-value

Hey I am trying to calculate,

\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}\left[\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)\right]
\end{align*}

Where $X_i$ ase iid Bernoulli distributions with probability $p$. I really just do not know how to approach calculating this. I feel like it should be simple.

Comment: If $X=\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ do you know how to find the pmf of $X$, namely $p_X$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling Not really. Is it just the max of the individual Bernoulli pmf?

Comment: No. You need to find $p_X(0)$ and $p_X(1)$. Once you find these values, your expectation becomes $$E(X)=0\cdot p_X(0) + 1\cdot p_X(1)$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling $P_X(0) = (1-p)^3$ and $P_X(1) = p^3$

Comment: @MatthewPilling Okay so $E(X)=E(max(X_1,X_2,X_3) = p^3$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling I see an error I made, $P_X(0) = (1-p)^3$, $P_X(1)=p$ (because only one need to succeed). Making $E(X)=p$

Comment: @MatthewPilling or is $P_X(1) = (3p + 2p^2 + p^3)/6$?

Comment: $p_X(0)=(1-p)^3$ is correct, which means that $$p_X(1)=1-p_X(0)=1-(1-p)^3$$ For $\{X=1\}$ to occur we need *at least* one of the $X_i$'s to be 1. The probability of such an event occuring is not equal to $p$. To find this probability directly, you need to examine in how many ways we can get at least one $X_i$ to equal $1$